# What is the correct way of reading from 2 endpoints and displaying it in 1 table using ajax?

Tags: ajax, datatables

I have 2 tables(endpoints) - **users** and **leaderboard**. In **users** table their are columns **user_id** and **full_name**. In **leaderboard** table there is a **user_id** column and other columns. I want to display **leaderboard** table. But instead of **user_id** I want to show **full_name** column.

So I will have to take the **full_name** from the **users** table. This is my code:

1st ajax call -

```
var users = [];

$.ajax({
        url: url + "admin/users",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (result){
            for (i=0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                users[i] = result.data[i];
            }
        }
    })
```

2nd ajax call -

```
$.ajax({
        url: url + "admin/leaderboard",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (result){

            for (i=0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                var row = document.getElementById("table-body").insertRow(i);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                
                for (j=0 ; j < users.length ; j++) {

                    if (result.data[i].user_id === users[j]._id) {
                        cell1.innerHTML = users[j].full_name;
                        break;
                    } 
                    else {
                        cell1.innerHTML = 'NA';
                    }
                }

                cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].points;
            }

            $('#dataTable').DataTable();
        }
    })
```

The 2nd ajax call occurs only after the 1st ajax call is completed.

Right now I have only 15 rows in the users table. But later on there will be thousands of rows. If there are thousands of rows in the users endpoint then the 1st ajax call will take a long time to complete. It will have detrimental effects to the end user's experience. So what would be the correct way of coding it?

The code is working fine. The only issue is the speed.

Comment: What type of database are you using to store your data? Normal practise using an SQL based database would be to join the tables before you fetch the records. This way you can get your data using a single endpoint.

Comment: @mark_b Thanks. It's all json data that I am using at the backend.